# Importing test in clojure

Tags: clojure

`deps.edn`:

```
{:paths ["test" "src"]
 :deps
 {clojure.java-time/clojure.java-time {:mvn/version "0.3.2"}}}
```

in `doppelkopf/test/`

```
(ns doppelkopf.core-test
  (:require
    [clojure.test :as test]
    [doppelkopf.src.core :refer :all]))

(test/deftest addition
  (test/is (= 5 (+ 2 3)) "addition")
  (test/is (= 4 (+ 3 1))))
```

In `doppelkopf/src/` I have my `core.clj`

i got the following error, when evaluating `test.clj`:

```
 Show: Project-Only All 
  Hide: Clojure Java REPL Tooling Duplicates  (20 frames hidden)

2. Unhandled clojure.lang.Compiler$CompilerException
   Error compiling core_test.clj at (1:1)
   #:clojure.error{:phase :execution,
                   :line 1,
                   :column 1,
                   :source
                   "/home/dave/ClojureProjects/doppelkopf/test/core_test.clj"}
             Compiler.java: 7665  clojure.lang.Compiler/load
                      REPL:    1  user/eval7600
                      REPL:    1  user/eval7600
             Compiler.java: 7194  clojure.lang.Compiler/eval
             Compiler.java: 7149  clojure.lang.Compiler/eval
                  core.clj: 3215  clojure.core/eval
                  core.clj: 3211  clojure.core/eval
    interruptible_eval.clj:   87  nrepl.middleware.interruptible-eval/evaluate/fn/fn
                  AFn.java:  152  clojure.lang.AFn/applyToHelper
                  AFn.java:  144  clojure.lang.AFn/applyTo
                  core.clj:  667  clojure.core/apply
                  core.clj: 1990  clojure.core/with-bindings*
                  core.clj: 1990  clojure.core/with-bindings*
               RestFn.java:  425  clojure.lang.RestFn/invoke
    interruptible_eval.clj:   87  nrepl.middleware.interruptible-eval/evaluate/fn
                  main.clj:  437  clojure.main/repl/read-eval-print/fn
                  main.clj:  437  clojure.main/repl/read-eval-print
                  main.clj:  458  clojure.main/repl/fn
                  main.clj:  458  clojure.main/repl
                  main.clj:  368  clojure.main/repl
               RestFn.java: 1523  clojure.lang.RestFn/invoke
    interruptible_eval.clj:   84  nrepl.middleware.interruptible-eval/evaluate
    interruptible_eval.clj:   56  nrepl.middleware.interruptible-eval/evaluate
    interruptible_eval.clj:  152  nrepl.middleware.interruptible-eval/interruptible-eval/fn/fn
                  AFn.java:   22  clojure.lang.AFn/run
               session.clj:  218  nrepl.middleware.session/session-exec/main-loop/fn
               session.clj:  217  nrepl.middleware.session/session-exec/main-loop
                  AFn.java:   22  clojure.lang.AFn/run
               Thread.java:  829  java.lang.Thread/run

1. Caused by java.io.FileNotFoundException
   Could not locate doppelkopf/src/core__init.class, doppelkopf/src/core.clj or
   doppelkopf/src/core.cljc on classpath.
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You've showed us (some of) your source, but you haven't shown us what symptoms lead you to believe that it has a problem.

Comment: BTW, there are two different ways to start and end code formatting. One is with four-space indents on each line that should be code-formatted, the other is with lines containing three backticks at the top and bottom of each code section. (The three-backtick way gives you somewhat more control: when using it, you can specify how to syntax-highlight each segment by putting the name of the relevant language next to the opening backticks with no spaces separating, should the autodetection not get it right).

Comment: ...okay, thank you for adding that. The error message claims that you _don't_ have a file named `doppelkopf/src/core.clj`. A [mre] we can run ourselves (f/e, in an online sandbox like https://repl.it/) where that file exists but the same error occurs would be helpful. (Another way I've built [mre]s for this class of problem myself in the past is writing a script that creates the directory and file structure, such that someone else can run that script themselves and then do the build on their own workstation).

Comment: BTW, where exactly is `deps.edn`? Is it in the `doppelkopf` directory, or is it in `ClojureProjects` directly?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy now it works, i just restarted my REPL. I do not know what is the problem. THank you!

Comment: BTW, looking a little more closely at the question, I think the difference between `doppelkonf/src/core.clj` and `doppelkonf/src/doppelkonf/core.clj` might be a pertinent one. Because `doppelkonf/src` is where the search tree for non-test sources starts, a `doppelkonf` directory is expected to exist _under that_.

Comment: ...mind, the namespace hosted in `doppelkonf/src/doppelkonf/core.clj` would be expected to be called `doppelkonf.core`, not `doppelkonf.src.core`.

Comment: did you create the folder structure using lein?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your project structure and/or your namespace names are off.

Your Project is in `$HOME/ClojureProjects/doppelkopf` (I'll use `$P` for
that from here on), where (hopefully) your `deps.edn` resides.  Then
from there you have added `src` and `test` as source roots and by that
also as class-path items for the compiled code.

So now we can assume, you have a `doppelkopf.core` namespace, because
you want to write a `doppelkopf.core-test` test for it.

So the file locations have to be:

- `$P/src/doppelkopf/core.clj` with (most likely already correct) `(ns doppelkopf.core ...)`
- `$P/test/doppelkopf/core_test.clj` with the shown `(ns doppelkopf.core-test ...)`

The most important points:

- the dotted (`.`) parts of the namespace must mirror back into the file
  system
- the dashes (`-`) in the namespace must be "munged", which means, a `-`
  in the namespace must be a underscore `_` in the file system; this is
  a restriction from the JVM

Comment: Thank you, my deps.edn was still in my src file.